Combining more than 2 GPUs for gaming
I have seen rigs for multiple GPUs used for training AI, crypto mining, and password cracking, and I'm wondering if something similar could be done for gaming?
In trying to research this on my own, most of what info I find is really only about mining, and those setups don't seem to work for gaming, because they are, from the little I understand, reducing the number of data lines going to each GPU, so it reduces the speed of communication. But I imagine for AI or password cracking, it might have to be different?
If you did try something like this for gaming, what would the setup have to look like? Scenarios I've imagined, which may be totally unfounded, are things like: Would it have to be some kind of custom motherboard that can handle more GPUs? or is there some kind of board that could handle coordinating the different GPUs together and plugged into a single PCIe slot, with its own power supply, that would act like a single GPU? Could you use different types of GPUs, or would they have to be the same?
If this isn't possible, what are the limiting factors?

Previous incarnations would have been SLI (Nvidia) or Crossfire (AMD) and require specialised links between the GPUs to synchronise data and screen information. It has been largely deprecated in favour of GPUs which actually have enough power combined with upscaling methods that reduce the required GPU power.

Essentially, you would need to create a game from the ground up to take advantage of multiple GPUs. The software, not the hardware, is the largest barrier - assuming you meant to have the additional GPU(s) providing a "reasonable" performance uplift relative to the additional cost.
Ashes of the Singularity supports explicit multi-GPU (i.e. game-based) via DirectX. There are likely a few other titles that have some level of support as well.
Previous implicit multi-GPU technologies, AMD CrossFireX and NVIDIA SLI, fell out of favor as games moved towards more and more post-processing and temporal effects, coinciding and driven further by the launch of DirectX12. These changes in game software created technical hurdles that prevent worthwhile performance scaling by adding additional GPUs using the implicit multi-GPU path (i.e. driver-based). Although a variety of techniques were possible, most implicit multi-GPU relied upon alternate-frame rendering, where one GPU rendered a frame and the next GPU in the system would render the next frame; the frame would then be relayed over a side-band bridge or over PCIe to the first GPU for display. Other techniques, such as split-frame rendering and checkerboard rendering were also done. The genesis of the technology was scanline interleaving, hence the original name by 3DFX of SLI.
Game developers don't generally invest in explicit multi-GPU due to performance scaling challenges, the amount of additional Q/A work that would need to be performed to service a small market, and the presence of a variety of other techniques to improve performance.
On the hardware side, only the ability to support 2 GPUs in the system would be required. I.e. enough PSU power and power connectors, enough PCIe connectors and lanes to run the GPUs, enough space in the chassis with any appropriate spacing required for cooling, and enough airflow through the chassis to keep the whole system cool. Some GPUs, like the NVIDIA TITAN Z and GeForce 7950GX2, came as multi-GPU combinations in one product. The TITAN Z kept everything on one board, whereas the 7950GX2, a much earlier design, used two GPU PCBs with an internal connection and PLX chip to support both the PCIe and side-band links. These designs didn't require any special motherboard considerations. Implicit multi-GPU required both GPUs to be the same, though not identical (e.g. 4x GeForce 480 RTX GPUs could be used in 4-way SLI, but they could be from different board manufacturers and with different clock speeds).
